# Calculate $\liminf_{n \to \infty} d(n)/\log(n)$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} d(n)/\log(n)$

Tags: number-theory

Calculate $\liminf_{n \to \infty} d(n)/\log(n)$  and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} d(n)/\log(n)$
$d(n)$ being the number of positive divisors for a positive integer $n$.

So from what I understand of limit superior and inferior, here's how I would approach the problem.

The lower bound of $d(n)$ as n approaches infinity is 2, as there infinitly many prime numbers, and the only positive dividers of prime numbers are 1 and itself.

The upper bound of $d(n)$ is infinity, as if $n$ is composite, then it would it have infinite amount of positive disviors as n approaches infinty.

So, as such, the  $\liminf_{n \to \infty} d(n)/\log(n)$ would be $2/\infty$, which would just $0$,
while $\limsup_{n \to \infty} d(n)/\log(n)$ would be $\infty/\infty$, would would just be $1$.
Or did get them reversed/wrong?

Comment: Be careful. You are right with the inferior limit, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n / b_n$ when both $a_n$ and $b:n$ tend to infinity is *not* always $1$: If e.g. $a_n = n$ and $b_n = n^2$, the limit is $0$, for $a_n = 42 n, b_n = n$ it is $42$, $a_n = n^4, b_n = n^3$ gives $\infty$.

Comment: Off the top of my head, some reasonable extreme cases to try would be primes (as you already did for the $\liminf$); $2^k$; and $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$ where $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ enumerate the primes in order.  For example, $d(2^k) = k+1$ so $\frac{d(2^k)}{\log(2^k)} = \frac{k+1}{k \log(2)} \to \frac{1}{\log(2)}$ as $k \to \infty$ (and note that $\frac{1}{\log(2)} > 1$).  The asymptotic behavior of the function on $p_1 \cdots p_k$ is a bit trickier, involving the prime number theorem, and I'll leave it to you to investigate that case.

Comment: It seems that using $d(k!) \ge 2^{\pi(k)}$, $\pi(k) \sim \frac{k}{\log k}$ by the prime number theorem, and $\log(k!) \sim k \log k$, you should be able to conclude that $\frac{d(k!)}{\log(k!)} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$, implying that $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{d(n)}{\log n} = \infty$.

Comment: One doesn't need complicated constructions or the prime number theorem for $\limsup$, since $d(6^k)=(k+1)^2$, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

First, for all prime number $p$, $d(p)=2$ and thus $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{d(n)}{n}=0$. As for the upper bound, let $n_k:=p_1\ldots p_k$, then $d(n_k)=2^k$ and
$$ \ln n_k=\vartheta(p_k)\leqslant\pi(n_k)\ln p_k=k\ln p_k $$
Thus $d(n_k)\geqslant 2^{\frac{\ln n_k}{\ln p_k}}$. But since $\ln n_k=\vartheta(p_k)\gg p_k$, we have $d(n_k)\geqslant\exp\left(\frac{\ln (2)\ln(n_k)}{\ln\ln n_k+\ln A}\right)$ for some constant $A>0$ such that $p_k\leqslant A\ln n_k$ for all $k\geqslant 1$. We thus have $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{d(n_k)}{\ln n_k}=+\infty$ and finally $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{d(n)}{\ln n}=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the inferior limit is $0$.

For the upper limit you have to identify "small" integers with lots of divisors. An extreme case are the powers of $2$: $2^k$ has the $k$ divisors $1, 2, \dotsc, 2^k$, for $k + 1$ in all. Would need to prove no number up to $2^k$ has more than $k + 1$ divisors (or find numbers with more) to derive your limit.

Comment: Is it something along the lines of a $n$ can be represented as a product of primes. Thus the number of divisors is $d(n) = (k_1 + 1)(k_2 +1)... (k_r + 1)$ where $k$ is the exponents of each unique prime. Thus if $n is 2^k$, then it would have $k+1$ divisors, but if it is not, then I'm am not sure how to show it is less :(